# Combo box Selected Value to Label Text Converter in silver light

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a combo box and label in Telerik Data Grid .I Want to bind the label text to combo box selected value changed .I need a converter to bind Combo box selected value to label text in order to change the label text according to Combo Box selected value changed .

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) And what is your question?

Comment: I want to change the label text on Combo box sleeted item change through binding in silver light. @ Clemens